# Python ctypes for HANDLE

Tags: python, dll, ctypes

I have a DLL function with prototype as follow:

```
short Connect(HANDLE* pHandle, UINT* pTimerID, LPCTSTR strDestination, LPCTSTR strServiceName, int nProtocol, int nType)
```

The function description as follow:

```
pHandle:  socket handle.[out]
pTimerID: Timer ID using sending alive packet to a camera.[out]
strDestination: camera network IP.[in]
strServiceName: camera network port.[in]
nProtocol: address family(AF_INET).[in]
nType: Socket type(SOCK_STREAM or SCOK_DGRAM).[in]
```

I try to call it DLL from python as follow:

```
DLL = windll.LoadLibrary('myDll.dll')
self.UserID = 0
self.keepAliveID = 0
DLL.Connect.restype = ctypes.c_short
DLL.Connect.argtypes = [c_void_p, c_ulong, c_wchar_p, c_wchar_p, c_int, c_int]
try:
    err = DLL.Connect(self.UserID,self.keepAliveID,self.ip,self.port,2,1)
    if err == -1:
        print "connect ErrorCode = ", err
except:
    print "connect Exception = ", sys.exc_info()
```

After run the program I got this exception:

```
connect Exception =  (<type 'exceptions.WindowsError'>, WindowsError('exception: access violation writing 0x00000000',), <traceback object at 0x0262C300>)
```

1. Where are my mistakes?
2. What is data type of HANDLE in C++ DLL and how to use ctypes to convert it?

The second question is when I change `argtypes` as follows:

```
DLL.Connect.argtypes = [c_void_p, POINTER(c_ulong), c_wchar_p, c_wchar_p, c_int, c_int]
```

Then I get another exception:

```
connect Exception =  (<class 'ctypes.ArgumentError'>, ArgumentError("argument 2: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: expected LP_c_ulong instance instead of int",), <traceback object at 0x0261A328>)
```

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try redefining the function call like this:

```
from ctypes import *
from ctypes.wintypes import *

dll = WinDLL('myDll.dll')
connect = dll.Connect
connect.restype = c_short
connect.argtypes = [POINTER(HANDLE), POINTER(UINT), LPCWSTR, LPCWSTR, c_int, c_int)
```

And call like this, using `byref` to pass by reference:

```
self.user_id = HANDLE()
self.keep_alive_id = UINT()
err = connect(byref(self.user_id), byref(self.keep_alive_id), self.ip, self.port, 2, 1)
```

Untested of course but this should at least get you closer.

Comment: Thank you figs, I try but it will have another exception "connect ErrorCode =  -1", I check the dll document -1 means <No handle>

Comment: Hard to know without reading the DLL's docs. You could try making the first argument `c_void_p` instead of `POINTER(c_ulong)` and call _without_ the `byref`.

Comment: Connect.argtypes = [c_void_p,POINTER(c_uint),c_wchar_p,c_wchar_p,c_int,c_int]
Connect((self.UserID),byref(self.keepAliveID),self.ip,self.port,2,1)
connect Exception =  (<class 'ctypes.ArgumentError'>, ArgumentError("argument 1: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: wrong type",), <traceback object at 0x0278B328>)